# Modify image displayed by OS on screen with OpenGL?

Tags: linux, opengl

What I want to achieve is to real time transform the image displayed by my linux system i.e. I would like to be able to achieve true gray scale so for every pixel of the screen we would have each rgb value set to be equal to average of what would be normally displayed.

I guess it would be possible to take the buffer, modify it in C and save it back, but that approach would waste lots of systems resources. Is there other way?

Comment: By "image displayed by OS" do you mean the entire screen?

Comment: What do you mean "by OS on screen"?  Via X11?  Wayland?  Linux framebuffer?

Comment: X11, so it does make a difference? Entire screen, everything you can see from first to last pixel

Comment: My bet then that you'll need to use a compositing window manager and modify it to apply your color transformation during the composition.